# using Agora - PlatformException(7, not initialized, null, null)

Tags: android, flutter, video-streaming, flutter-dependencies, agora.io

```
E/flutter (31727): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(7, not initialized, null, null)
E/flutter (31727): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
E/flutter (31727): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:167:18)
E/flutter (31727): <asynchronous suspension>
```

I am using [Agora](https://docs.agora.io/en/live-streaming/API%20Reference/flutter/index.html) for Flutter for video broadcasting.
I am getting above exceptions when I leave channel and destroy rtc engine. Any hints to fix this? There are no logs suggesting reason for the error.

Answer (score 1):

[here](https://docs.agora.io/en/live-streaming/API%20Reference/flutter/agora_rtc_engine/ErrorCode.html):

> const ErrorCode(7)
> NotReady → const ErrorCode
> The SDK module is not ready. Possible
> solutions:
> Check the audio device.
> Check the completeness of the app.
> Re-initialize the SDK.

You may check your code about the engine's `create`.

Answer (score 1):

The error code 7 occurs when the SDK fails to initialize. Most commonly the error can be due to an incorrect APP ID or missing/expired token.